# Why does the existence of a dispersion point imply total path disconnectedness?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

In a comment of [Fractal of the topologist's sine curve is connected and totally path-disconnected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807045/fractal-of-the-topologists-sine-curve-is-connected-and-totally-path-disconnecte) M W asserts that the existence of a [dispersion point](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000045), a point for which the removal of results in a [totally disconnected](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000047) space, implies that the space is [totally path disconnected](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000046) (even before the removal). Why must this be the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general. One needs to assume $X$ is at least $T_1$ in addition.

Ulli has already given a $T_0$ counterexample and a proof for Hausdorff spaces.

Let me add a proof in the case $X$ is only $T_1$.

In this case, suppose $x_0$ is a dispersion point of $X$, so $X\backslash \{x_0\}$ is totally disconnected. Suppose by contradiction $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to X$ is a nonconstant path in $X$.  Then since $\{x_0\}$ is closed, $\gamma^{-1}(\{x_0\})$ is closed.

Since $\gamma^{-1}(\{x_0\})$ is closed, its complement is a disjoint union of open intervals, and by total disconnectedness of $X\backslash \{x_0\}$, $\gamma$ is constant on each complementary interval. But then the preimage of any point  $x\in \gamma([0,1])\backslash \{x_0\}$ is open, hence not closed, (since $\gamma$ is nonconstant and $[0,1]$ is connected), contradicting the $T_1$ property of $X$.

##### Remark

We cannot replace $T_1$ by any weaker condition here, since
if $X$ is not $T_1$, then for some distinct $x,y\in X$ we have $x\in \overline{\{y\}}$, at which point $x$ and $y$ can be connected by the path in Ulli's counter-example:
$$\gamma(t)=
\begin{cases}
x & t=0\\
y & t\neq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
On the other hand, the existence of a dispersion point $x_0$ already implies $X\backslash \{x_0\}$ is $T_1$, so that verifying the $T_1$ condition in specific cases reduces to establishing that $x_0\notin \overline{\{x\}}$ and $x\notin \overline{\{x_0\}}$ for arbitrary $x\neq x_0$.

Comment: @M W: oh yes, about your remark, it didn't come to my mind: [$X$ totally path disconnected $\Rightarrow$ T1](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000049/references)

Comment: Thanks to both of you - this T1 result is a little tighter so I suppose it gets the green checkmark. And I should have thought to query https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=t_0%2B~Totally+Path+Disconnected%2BHas+a+Dispersion+Point before asking the question; thanks to you both we'll soon have a theorem showing https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=t_1%2B~Totally%20Path%20Disconnected%2BHas%20a%20Dispersion%20Point is impossible.

Comment: @MW In the last paragraph, without extra assumption it does seem to be true that the complement of the dispersion point singleton is Hausdorff.  For example one can take a non-Hausdorff totally disconnected space $Y$ (https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Totally%20Disconnected%2B~T2) and construct a space $X$ by adding a point $p$ and taking the open sets of $X$ to be the unions of an open set in $Y$ with $\{p\}$, together with the empty set.  $p$ is then a dispersion point but its complement is not Hausdorff.

Comment: @PatrickR yes, I changed the post earlier today for that reason [earlier I had falsely been thinking totally disconnected meant Hausdorff]- perhaps you are looking at a previous version?

Comment: Ah, yes.  I was indeed looking at an older version.

Answer (score 3):

This is true, if $X$ is T2:

Let $x_0$ be the dispersion point, and asssume $A \subset X$ is path-connected, $|A| \ge 2$. Then $x_0 \in A$.
Then, by T2, there is a $B \subset A$ such that $x_0 \in B$ and $B$ is homeomorphic to  $[0, 1]$. Then $x_0$ is dispersion point of $B$ as well, which is a contradiction, since $[0, 1]$ has no dispersion point.

If $X$ is only T0, this is false:

Let $X \neq \emptyset$ be an arbitrary set, $x_0 \in X$.
$\tau := \{U \subset X: x_0 \in U\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$
is a topology on $X$ with dispersion point $x_0$. Of course, $X$ is T0. 
$X$ is path-connected:
If $x \in X$, then
$f: [0, 1] \rightarrow X, \space
f(r) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} x, \text{ if } r = 0 \\ x_0, \text{ if } r \neq 0 \\
\end{array}  \right. \space $
is a path.

**Remark**

In case of T2, we also have the following elegant conclusions:

$X$ has a dispersion point $\Rightarrow$
$X$ is [SG](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4650561/what-are-some-interesting-properties-of-the-spaces-with-the-mentioned-property-e#comment9819521_4650561) $\Rightarrow$
$X$ is punctiform (i.e., the only non-empty, connected, compact subsets are the singletons)  $\Rightarrow$
$X$ is totally path disconnected

However, this does not hold in case of T1, as the one-point compactification of the rationals shows.
Hence, for the T1 case, M W's proof is definitely relevant.

Comment: beat me by seconds!

Comment: Apologies! Might be you know the answer in case of T1?